# Does Windows NT cache or flush INI-file writings?

Tags: windows, winapi, caching, flush, ini

I am updating a rather old application. It used INI file accesses all around the code, creating and freeing INI-accessing class instances here and there.

I want to centralize this to several single instances, one per used file.
So we'd get rid of instances creating/freeing copy-pasted everywhere and would have freedom to completely replace those classes would be decision to switch from INI to other settings storage.

Should one call WritePrivateProfileString(NULL, NULL, NULL...) to apply the changes?
Assume that:
1) the access goes directly to real INI-files, not to registry mapped ones.
2) OS is of NT family (maybe rarely Win2000, most probably WinXP and later). Win9x/ReactOS/WinE/Odin/etc are not cared about.

So, should we flush the ini savings now explicitly or not ?

NT does not cache Registry key writes, do no need to regFlushKey now.
But what about INI files?

MSDN page about WritePrivateProfileString only describes flushing technique wrt Win9x and NT File-to-Reg mappings. It is silent about real INI files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation contradicts itself (my bold):

> The system keeps a cached version of the most recent **registry file mapping** to improve performance. If all parameters are NULL, the function flushes the cache. While the system is editing the **cached version of the file**, processes that edit the file itself will use the original file until the cache has been cleared.

Is Windows caching the mapping or a file (what file)?  But the comment in the sample code makes it clear:

```
// Force the system to read the mapping into shared memory 
// so that future invocations of the application will see it 
// without the user having to reboot the system
```

It is the registry file **mapping** that is cached.  If you alter the mapping in the registry then you need to tell Windows to refresh its cache.

This is also consistent with usage of the API in Windows 3.1, where you didn't need to flush anything.  It's unlikely that Windows would fundamentally change the usage of the API.

To double-check, I called `WritePrivateProfileString` while running [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx).  As expected, Windows opens the INI file, updates it and closes it again.

No flushing required.

Comment: In Windows NT registry consists of several physical files.

Comment: Yeah, i would hope it changed in NT just like the registry writes.

ProcMon is a nice hint but it is not proving. Just because we simulate one-task environment and if Windows disk is not busy it would flush the cache, why not. But what if multiple threads/programs updated the same file ? What if the program crashed heavily?

Comment: Personally i read that place like "windows flushes content (just written values) of virtual ini-file to underlying real registry storage back end"

Comment: Did I misunderstand your question?  Aren't you using real INI files?  Then why do you care how the registry is implemented?  The comment in the sample code strongly implies that it is the mapping being cached because the flush is done after the mapping is created and before any calls to `WritePrivateProfileString`.  I guess this function runs in user mode, so if your app crashes hard enough at just the wrong time you'll probably get a corrupt INI file. Finally, INI writes have always been immediately available; adding an undocumented cache would break this assumption.

Comment: i do not "care", i just use it as a hint, how NT family in general differs in its priorities of 9x lineup. But such a breaking assumption was effective for 95/98.

Comment: He's saying that the documentation is not contradicting itself in the portions that you bolded. The answer to your rhetorical "what file?" question is that the Windows Registry is implemented as a series of files. That's the "file(s)" to which the quotation from the SDK documentation refers. It isn't talking about INI files there. Which gets us back to the original question: the docs talk about Win 9x flushing INI files and they talk about Win NT flushing registry-mapped INI files, but they don't say anything about Win NT flushing INI files.

Comment: And of course, "test it and see" (e.g., using Process Monitor) is not a very good strategy because it doesn't tell us what the *contract* is, it only tells us what the *current implementation* does. For that to be remotely useful, you'd have to test it on *all* supported operating systems. And then you'd still be screwed when a new version of the OS is released.

Comment: How can the documentation be referring to the registry backing files when it says "processes that edit the file itself will use the original file until the cache has been cleared"?  Processes cannot directly edit the registry backing files.  So the documentation cannot be referring to them.  I agree that "test it and see" is not a good strategy in general, but it can be useful when trying to make sense of documentation that is plainly wrong.